# Zero dual variables

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I am struggling to prove the following claim:

Primal problem (1)
$\max_{x \geq 0} c^Tx$
subject to
$Ax \leq b$ and
$Dx \leq d$

Primal problem (2)
$\max_{x \geq 0} c^Tx$
subject to
$Dx \leq d$

Suppose there exists a feasible solution $x^*$ for both problems that is also optimal for both problems.

Claim: optimal dual variable(s) (vector) $\lambda^*$ that corresponds to the set of constraints $Ax \leq b$ is zero.

Attempt:

$(D1$) is $\min_{\lambda \ge0, \ge0,} ^\lambda+^$ subject to $^\lambda+^\ge $. $(D2)$ is $\min_{\ge0} ^$ subject to $^\ge $. I can use complementary slackness here to deduce the following:

1. if $^∗,\lambda^∗,^∗$ solve $(P1)$ and $(D1)$, then $^∗(^\lambda^∗+^^∗−)=0$ and
2. if $^∗,\bar{}^∗$ solve $(P2),(D2)$, then $^∗(^\bar{}^∗−)=0$.

Comment: Hi, can you include your attempt?

Comment: The $\lambda^*$ is not necessarily unique.

Comment: The obvious first step is to write down the duals of the two primal problems.  Have you done that? If so, what are they? If not, why not?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera (D1) is $\min _{\lambda \geq 0, y \geq 0} b^T \lambda + d^T y$ subject to $A^T \lambda + D^T y \geq c$. (D2) is $\min _{ y \geq 0} d^T y$ subject to $D^T y \geq c$. I can use complementary slackness here to deduce the following: 1) if $x^*, \lambda^*, y^*$ solve (P1) and (D1), then $x^* (A^T \lambda^* + D^T y^* - c) = 0$ and 2) if $x^*, \overline{y}^*$ solve (P2),(D2), then $x^* (D^T \overline{y}^* - c) = 0$

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I tried complementary slackness and dualizing part of the variables, precisely the following lemma : Let $(x^*,y^*,\lambda^*)$ solve (P1) and (D1); then $x^*$ solves $\max c^T x + \lambda^* Dx$ subject to $Ax \leq b$. Nothing gives me zero. I think the biggest issue is that it is not true(maybe it is) that there exists $y*$ in (P1),(D1) which is the same as $\overline{y}^*$ in (D2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be interpreted as there exists such choice of $\lambda$ as $\lambda$ need not be unique. For example, consider the case where the matrices are all zeros, we can see that clearly $\lambda$ needs not be $0$.

From strong duality, we know that we can find $y^*$ that is the optimal solution to $(D2)$.

Now, check that $(\lambda, y)=(0, y^*)$ is a solution to $(D1)$ and attains the same optimal value as $(D2)$ and hence $(P1)$ by strong duality.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up!